# Android application in codeigniter?

Tags: android, codeigniter

Is it possible to develop android application in `codeigniter`? I have heard from few people that we can develop an application with `codeigniter`.

Comment: Yes, you can write the server/API portion of an Android application in CodeIgniter, or indeed in any PHP framework.

Answer (score 2):

`CodeIgniter` is `php` framework. The people telling you might be having context of `REST API` developed using `CodeIgniter`, and the Android app consuming that `API`.